# How to count the number of item in foreach loop based by it's parent?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a simple loop to display a list. But I do not know how to count it's parent item. This is my current attempt:

```
$no = 0;
$ct = 0;
$type = "";
foreach($item as $row_item){
   $no = $no + 1;

   if($type != $row_item['type']){
      $ct  = $ct + 1;
   }

   echo $no." ".$row_item['type']." ".$row_item['item'];


  $type = $row_item['type'];

}
```

My desired output :

```
1   TYPE_A   3   A1
2   TYPE_A   3   A2
3   TYPE_A   3   A3
4   TYPE_B   2   B1
5   TYPE_B   2   B2
```

Comment: what does `$item` look like to start off with?

Answer (score 0):

In order to count the total number of each type you'll need to iterate over the entire collection twice. Once to count the totals, and once to display the results for each row. The code below actually does 3 loops, the array_filter method iterates over the entire array, but I like the clean code. :)

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/962f418715d1518c818732f6e59ba4f28d5a19f3

```
<?php
$items = array( 
  array( 'name' => 'A1', 'type' => 'TYPE_A' ),
  array( 'name' => 'A2', 'type' => 'TYPE_A' ),
  array( 'name' => 'A3', 'type' => 'TYPE_A' ),
  array( 'name' => 'B1', 'type' => 'TYPE_B' ),
  array( 'name' => 'B2', 'type' => 'TYPE_B' )
);

function is_TYPE_A( $item ) {
  return $item['type'] == 'TYPE_A';
}
function is_TYPE_B( $item ) {
  return $item['type'] == 'TYPE_B';
}

$TYPE_A_COUNT = count( array_filter( $items, 'is_TYPE_A' ) );
$TYPE_B_COUNT = count( array_filter( $items, 'is_TYPE_B' ) );

function getTypeTotalByItem( $item ) {
  global $TYPE_A_COUNT, $TYPE_B_COUNT;
  if ( $item['type'] == 'TYPE_A' ) {
    return $TYPE_A_COUNT;
  }
  if ( $item['type'] == 'TYPE_B' ) {
    return $TYPE_B_COUNT;
  }
}

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $items ); $i++ ) {
  echo ( $i + 1 )." ".$items[$i]['type']." ".getTypeTotalByItem($items[$i])." ".$items[$i]['name']."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map()` and a couple `foreach()` loops for this if you were so inclined. It should interpret fairly quickly:

```
# Create a storage array
$counter    =   [];
# Sort the main array into type
array_map(function($v) use (&$counter){
    # Store the subs under the type
    $counter[$v['type']][]  =   $v['item'];
},$items);
# Start counter
$i = 1;
# Loop through each type
foreach($counter as $title => $row){
    # Count how many are under this type
    $count  =   count($row);
    # Loop the rows in the types arrays
    foreach($row as $item) {
        # Write increment, type, total count, item
        echo $i." ".$title." ".$count." ".$item.'<br />';
        $i++;
    }
}
```